# jQuery script to clear input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to write a jQuery script where when someone clicks on the input the space clears and then if they don't type anything in, it reappears.

This is what I came up with. Is there a better way to do this? If so why is it better?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // set all input.text default value according to alt attribute
            $("input.contactStyle").each(function(){
                $(this).val($(this).attr("alt"));
            });

            // clear input.text on focus, if still in default
            $("input.contactStyle").focus(function() {

                if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("alt")) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });

            // if field is empty afterward, add text again
            $("input.contactStyle").blur(function() {
                if($(this).val()=="") {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr("alt"));
                }
            });

            // set all input.text default value according to alt attribute
            $("textarea.contactStyle").each(function(){
                $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
            });

            // clear input.text on focus, if still in default
            $("textarea.contactStyle").focus(function() {

                if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("title")) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });

            // if field is empty afterward, add text again
            $("textarea.contactStyle").blur(function() {
                if($(this).val()=="") {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
                }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to recreate the functionality of the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute that exists in HTML5. For browsers that support it--and that's all modern browsers with the exception of IE9 (I think)--your above code can be replaced with e.g.:

```html
<input type="text" class="contactStyle" placeholder="Your placeholder text">
```

If you want to also use this functionality in less-modern browsers it'll take some JavaScript, but best not to reinvent the wheel. Several [polyfills](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) have been written by other people that let you use the `placeholder` attribute regardless of browser. There are several listed on [this page](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) (do a Ctrl+F for "placeholder").

Comment: Wow I did not know about the placeholder tag. That makes life a lot easier lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve your goal by using this simple plugin [jQuery clearfield](http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2009/08/02/jquery-plugin-clearfield/). This plugin is very simple and easy to use

Comment: It looks that the last letters are missing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two additional comments to @Jordan's great answer:

For custom attributes you should be using the `data-` suffix as suggested by the HTML5 spec: `data-alt`.
Here is a good short read on this: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

If you decide to go the extra mile and apply progressive enhancement to non-conformant browsers, here is a good and very related answer on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557801/can-i-use-jquery-to-blank-textarea-fields-or-ajax-like-input-boxes/7557994#7557994